# How to embed QML toolbar and menubar into QMainWindow

Tags: qt, qml

I am using `QWT` library to plot data. It seems that it is not possible to embed `QWidget` into `QML Quick 2`. So, I decided to create `QMainWindow` as my main window and create its toolbar and menubar using `Quick Controls`. How should I embed that qml toolbar and menubar into `QMainWindow`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create QML `ApplicationWindow` with QML MenuBar and ToolBar

main.qml

```
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: false
    menuBar: MenuBar {
        Menu {
            title: "Edit"
            MenuItem {
                text: "Cut"
            }
        }
    }
    toolBar: ToolBar {
        Row {
            anchors.fill: parent
            ToolButton {
                iconSource: "1.png"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///main.qml")));
```

Then get pointer to your `ApplicationWindow`

```
QWindow *qmlWindow = qobject_cast<QWindow*>(engine.rootObjects().at(0));
```

Create window container, by using [QWidget::createWindowContainer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#createWindowContainer)

```
QWidget *container = QWidget::createWindowContainer(qmlWindow);
container->setMinimumSize(qmlWindow->size());
```

And place container to the top of your widget

```
QWidget *widget = new QWidget();
QGridLayout *grid = new QGridLayout(widget);
grid->addWidget(container,0,0);
grid->addWidget(new QPushButton(widget),1,0);
widget->show();
```

Comment: Yes, I know it. But how to add menu bar ant tool bar?

Comment: It works. Instead of `QWidged` I used `QMainWindow` and added menuBar as `mainwindow->setMenuWidget (container);`. It is also necessary: `container->setMinimumSize (qmlWindow->size ().width (), qmlWindow->size ().height ()+30);` otherwise menubar is cutted