# How to get a QMainWindow from ApplicationWindow QML file to allow use of QDockWidget with QML files

Tags: qt, qml

I am using Qt 5.5.0
I am trying to use QDockWidget with QML files.
My main.qml is currently set up to be an Application window with a set of buttons that are intended to select the various QML ‘page’ files, which I want to open in dockable windows.

I want these page selection buttons to be in a QML file, located in a fixed area of the screen.
Currently these buttons are in the ToolBar section, to achieve this and main.qml is set up to be an ApplicationWindow.

In order to use QDockWidget, I need a QMainWindow.
I have tried to follow the example given in
[How to embed QML toolbar and menubar into QMainWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27167439/how-to-embed-qml-toolbar-and-menubar-into-qmainwindow)

So in main.cpp, I have tried to get a QMainWindow associated with my main.qml, as follows:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QQmlEngine>
#include <QtQml>
#include <QtQuick>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QQuickWidget>

#include "pageset.h"

QMainWindow* GlobalMainWindow;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<PageSet>("pagesetter", 1, 0, "MyPageSet");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("main.qml")));

//I’ve added the following just to try and get a QMainWindow....

    QObject *rootObject = engine.rootObjects().first();
    QQuickWindow *qmlWindow = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow *>(rootObject);

    /* From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27167439/how-to-embed-qml-toolbar-and-menubar-into-qmainwindow */
    QWidget *container = QWidget::createWindowContainer(qmlWindow);
    container->setMinimumSize(qmlWindow->size());   //This IS required!

    //Place container to the top of your widget

    QMainWindow *mainwindow = new QMainWindow();
    GlobalMainWindow = mainwindow;
    //NB. Crashes without setMenuWidget!!
    mainwindow->setMenuWidget(container);

    //At first, get a small white border around the qml window - and no buttons are responsive
    //then if you somehow adjust size so it 'snaps', all looks ok and buttons work!
    mainwindow->setMinimumSize(qmlWindow->size());   //??
    mainwindow->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

I’m not sure if the above use of QMainWindow is valid, since the QML file displays fine without any of the code between engine.load and return.

Anyway, my main.qml is something like:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.2
import pagesetter 1.0

ApplicationWindow
{
    title: qsTr("Test")
    visible: true
    width:1080
    height:720

    MyPageSet{
        id: pageSet
    }

    toolBar: ToolBar{
        GridLayout{
        x: 4; anchors.top: parent.top; anchors.bottomMargin: 4; anchors.fill:parent
        rows: 2;
        columns: 5;

        Button 
        {
            Layout.fillWidth: true; Layout.fillHeight: true;
            text: "page1"; checkable: true; 
            onClicked:
            {
               pageSet.display("Page1.qml")
            }
        }
        }   //End of Grid

    }   //End of toolbar
}
```

Where MyPageSet is registered as a C++ class ‘PageSet’, with ‘display’ method as follows:

```
void PageSet::display(QString file)
{
   QDockWidget *dock = new QDockWidget(tr("DockWidget name TBD"), GlobalMainWindow);

   QQuickView *view = new QQuickView();

   QWidget *container = QWidget::createWindowContainer(view, dock);
   container->setMinimumSize(200, 200);
   container->setMaximumSize(200, 200);
   container->setFocusPolicy(Qt::TabFocus);

   view->setSource(QUrl(file));


   dock->setWidget(container);

   GlobalMainWindow->addDockWidget(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea, dock);
}
```

Page1.qml is

```
Rectangle
{
 ...various buttons
}
```

The code runs but although I can see the Page1.qml file is loaded (I have debug in various custom types when they are created), I do not see the page displayed.

I suspect this is due to my QMainWindow not really being what I need it be to.

I know that Page1.qml can be displayed correctly if I just add it directly to main.qml, so I do not think there is anything wrong with that.

Can anyone advise how I should go about getting a QMainWindow so that I can attach dock widgets to it, or any other suggestions as to what I am doing wrong and why nothing is displayed.

Comment: I recomend you to use KDDockWidget instead of doing it yourself, they have qml support
https://github.com/KDAB/KDDockWidgets

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43234163/how-to-insert-qml-view-in-a-qwidget