# Docking in QtQuick

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

As far as I understand there is no built-in functionality for dockable containers in QtQuick. I found a few sources where this is added, however I am having trouble deciding which way to go.

https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/dev/custom_components/index.html

[How to get a QMainWindow from ApplicationWindow QML file to allow use of QDockWidget with QML files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33260132/how-to-get-a-qmainwindow-from-applicationwindow-qml-file-to-allow-use-of-qdockwi)

Can someone recommend a way (or preferably a library) to add docking to QtQuick?

Comment: There is nothing for the time being, however it is not that hard to DIY.

Comment: I guess "not that hard" is in the eye of the beholder, as I am fairly new to this. Do you have a pointer how to implement this? Is reparenting to a new window a feasible way to implement the "undocked" state?

Comment: Yes, if you are willing to go for multi-window. You could also have a floating element within the current window.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a solution that works with multiple windows moving a widget from the main window (docked state) to a new window (undocked state).

Hoping that this is useful to others here is a complete example:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Window {
        width: 100;
        height: 100;
        visible: false;
        id: wnd

        Rectangle {
            id: greenRect
            anchors.fill: parent
        }

        onClosing: {
            blueRect.state = "docked"
        }

    }

    Item {
        width: 200; height: 100

        Rectangle {
            id: redRect
            anchors.fill: parent
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: blueRect
            width: 50; height: 50
            x: 10; y: 10;
            color: "blue"

            states: [
                State {
                    name: "undocked"
                    ParentChange { target: blueRect; parent: greenRect; x: 10; y: 10 }
                },
                State {
                    name: "docked"
                    ParentChange { target: blueRect; parent: redRect; x: 10; y: 10 }
                }
            ]

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent;
                onClicked: {
                    blueRect.state = "undocked"
                    wnd.visible = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide a way to make it dockable like Visual studio widget, by dragging the titlebar of the window to desired location? have you implemented something like that ?