# How to "embed" one window inside another

Tags: qt, qml

I have inherited a Qt-based app that handles the master/detail relationship by presenting the detail screens as separate windows. The main window includes a list, and when you tap on a row a separate detail window is opened up.

In the code base, the detail windows are handled by a QML file and a matching .cpp file (the main window also has its own .cpp file). The problem I am facing is that a new client wants me to modify this application for them, except that they want everything to occur within a single window. They want the list to be shown on the left side, and then when a user taps a row, the detail screen is to be shown on the right side of the window in its own panel (but not in a separate window).

For various reasons I can't easily refactor this application. A quicker solution for me would be to continue to present the detail screen in its own window, but to make it a borderless window and position this borderless window over top of the main window (on the right) so that it appears to be a panel within the main window.

Is something like this possible with Qt? I have written Windows apps in the past that hooked into the Windows API to do something like, but I don't know whether this is even possible in a native Mac OS app, so I don't know whether Qt can handle it in some way automaticaly.

Comment: You can probably separate part of reusable UI in own `Item {}` type and use it either inside or outside of certain container. If you can only deal with QML then it probably implies creating a new .qml file out of that separated item and either putting it to resource file or in the directory with other qml files depending on how the app project organized.

Comment: I agree with refactoring into Items. I recently had a similar problem and discovered reparenting as the way to implement docking behavior: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41490652/docking-in-qtquick/41520315#41520315

Comment: @AlexanderVX: the reason I can't really refactor this is that I am basically making a copy of our main application and then modifying my copy. After I make these changes, I will need to continue to update my copy with changes that have been made to the original (in other words I will need to keep my copy in sync with the original). The more drastic the changes I make to my copy, the more difficult the synchronization will be. I did this once already for one of our clients, but since 99% of my changes were on the QML side, keeping the versions synced was not a huge problem subsequently.

Comment: @HerrvonWurst: Thanks, I'll take a look at what you've done and see if I can use it for what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could try is to create a widget based "main" window and then use `QWidget::createWindowContainer()` to wrap the QtQuick windows for positioning them with QtWidget means, e.g. layouts.