# Is it possible to add a QML item to the window created in mainwindow.ui form?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qt5.5

I have created a simple Qt application. I made the application interface in the mainwindow.ui form using the design mode. Now, I would like to add a places map to my program. I know I can do this using QML. However, I would like the map to be displayed in the same window as the other elements that I have already created without using QML. Is it possible to add this map to the same window or do I have to do something else?

Comment: please provide [mcve]. Anyway, I would recommend you to learn QML first, at least the basic things. Take a look at [QML book](https://qmlbook.github.io/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert QML view in a QWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43234163/how-to-insert-qml-view-in-a-qwidget)

Comment: @Amfasis Oh, yes. Thank you very much.